# how to select table column by column header name with xpath

Tags: select, xpath

I have a table of results and it looks like following:

```xhtml
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Expiration</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>123</td>
      <td>Paper</td>
      <td>10 pcs.</td>
      <td>$10</td>
      <td>Premium Copier paper</td>
      <td>None</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>321</td>
      <td>Paper</td>
      <td>20 pcs.</td>
      <td>$20</td>
      <td>Extra Copier paper</td>
      <td>None</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

And i want to select the whole column by its name with xpath e.g. i want the returned result to be an array of `{<td>$10</td>, <td>$20</td>}` if selected by column name "Price".
I'm new to xpath and not really sure how to do this, but i'm pretty sure it's possible.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ok, i've found the answer that would suffice and look quite elegant. Here goes the required XPath string:

```
//table/tbody/tr/td[count(//table/thead/tr/th[.="$columnName"]/preceding-sibling::th)+1]
```

Put a name of the column instead of $columnName. This works well for me. There's no XSL or anything, just pure xpath string. How to apply it - it's another question.

Comment: Note that this checks for an exact match of the column name. If your column name does not match at the time the XPath is evaluated (for example, you are using this in Selenium and the column name gets changed by Javascript), the "count()" predicate will return a 0, so instead of an error, you will always get the *first* column in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this XPath:

```
/table/tbody/tr/td[count(preceding-sibling::td)+1 = count(ancestor::table/thead/tr/th[.='Price']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]
```

I would think testing the position (`position()`) of the `td` against the position of the relevant `th` would work, but it didn't seem to when I was testing.

Comment: This seem not to work. No idea why, but i've found the solution already.

Comment: @EduardSukharev - You should add your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Yes, but i'm low on points so couldn't add my own solution for the first 6 hours.

Answer (score 1):

If you've found a solution, I suggest posting it as an answer here, but just for fun, this is how I would approach this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="kCol" match="td" use="count(. | preceding-sibling::td)"/>
  <xsl:param name="column" select="'Price'" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <found>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="table/thead/tr/th" />
    </found>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="th">
    <xsl:if test=". = $column">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kCol', position())" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run with "Price" as the parameter value:

```
<found>
  <td>$10</td>
  <td>$20</td>
</found>
```

When run with "Name" as the parameter value:

```
<found>
  <td>Premium Copier paper</td>
  <td>Extra Copier paper</td>
</found>
```