# python xpath returns empty list

Tags: python-3.x, xpath

The following code returns an empty list

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html

YrlyURL=str("http://www.moneycontrol.com/financials/20microns/balance-sheetVI/2M#2M")
page3 = requests.get(YrlyURL, timeout=5)
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(page3.content, "lxml")
tree2 = html.fromstring(page3.content)
yr1 = tree2.xpath('//*[@id="mc_mainWrapper"]/div[3]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]')
print(yr1)
```

I need yr1 to return 'Mar 17', but I am not able to find a solution. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong and where I need to make the correction.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

This xpath will return the whole column

`'//table[@class="table4"]/tr/td[count(//table[@class="table4" and ./tr/td[.="Mar 17"]]/preceding-sibling::tr)+2]'`

`<td class="detb" align="right">Mar 17</td>
<td class="det" align="right">12 mths</td>
<td class="detb" align="right"></td>
<td class="detb" align="right"></td>
<td class="det" align="right">17.64</td>
<td class="hed" align="right">17.64</td>
<td class="det" align="right">79.08</td>
<td class="hed" align="right">79.08</td>
<!-- more tds -->`

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745478/how-to-select-table-column-by-column-header-name-with-xpath).

Comment: Thanks for this Luis it helps, but I need to know why my own code fails and returns an empty list.

Comment: I suggest to save the html to a file and debug you own xpath on command line with xmllint or other tool so you make sure first your xpath works. BTW, your xpath is similar to those taken from browser dev tool which are generic and not always suitable for code.